# GWT 2.7.0 superDevMode recompiling (cache.js.gz error)

Tags: eclipse, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode, gwt-compiler

I am using eclipse to develop a gwt application and recently I migrated from GWT 2.6.0 to 2.7.0. I was always using super dev mode(with built-in jetty) and it worked ok with 2.6. While using superdev mode on 2.7 it has become quite frequent for the linker to not detect the cache.js.gz and it seems like this causes gwt to generate an insane amount of recompiles with a simple refresh(pressing F5 on firefox).
Recently I cleared my Temp folder with ccleaner and I am not sure if this affected the files used for the jetty codeserver. Though normally every time you run a gwt app it generates all the necessary files in the Temp/ folder.

Here is a sample log:

```
 >Super Dev Mode starting up 
 >  workDir: C:\Users\Georgios\AppData\Local\Temp\gwt-codeserver-8575962486520173754.tmp

>GET /recompile/aanwebappv1
>Job com.aan.main.AanWebAppV1_1_9
>starting job: com.aan.main.AanWebAppV1_1_1
>binding: user.agent=gecko1_8
>skipped compile because no input files have changed
  0.091s total -- Compile completed

>GET /aanwebappv1/164467EFAF74C025EFC82CAB8189FED3.cache.js
>  Sent error page: not found: C:\Users\Georgios\AppData\Local\Temp\gwt-codeserver-8575962486520173754.tmp\com.aan.main.AanWebAppV1\compile-2\war\aanwebappv1\164467EFAF74C025EFC82CAB8189FED3.cache.js.gz
>starting job: com.aan.main.AanWebAppV1_1_5
>GET /recompile/aanwebappv1
>Job com.aan.main.AanWebAppV1_1_10
  binding: user.agent=gecko1_8
  skipped compile because no input files have changed
> 0.081s total -- Compile completed

> starting job: com.aan.main.AanWebAppV1_1_6
>GET /aanwebappv1/4D923033DA748FA380787E84FE5C58B9.cache.js
>Sent error page: not found: C:\Users\Georgios\AppData\Local\Temp\gwt-codeserver-8575962486520173754.tmp\com.aan.main.AanWebAppV1\compile-2\war\aanwebappv1\4D923033DA748FA380787E84FE5C58B9.cache.js.gz
```

This [GET/recompile-starting job-Sent error page: not found:]  cycle goes on and on generating 30-40 compiles or even more slowing the debugging process greatly...It even happens on the first compile sometimes..Any thoughts-ideas how to fix this?